# How to get into details view from another details view and get all the queryset in template properly?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I need to get into details view from another details view..but i can't pass the queryset clearly...

In models:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    mega_league = models.ManyToManyField('MegaLeague', blank=True)


class MegaPricePoolBreak(models.Model):
    pass


class MegaLeague(models.Model):
    price_pool_break = models.ManyToManyField(MegaPricePoolBreak, blank=True)
```

In views:

```
def league(request):
    match = Match.objects.all()
    context = {
        'match': match,
    }
    return render(request, 'main/league.html', context=context)


def league_detail(request, pk):
    match = get_object_or_404(Match, pk=pk)
    context = {
        'match': match,
    }
    return render(request, 'main/league_detail.html', context=context)


def league_detail_more(request, pk):
    match = get_object_or_404(Match, pk=pk)
    context = {
        'match': match,
        'title': 'select matches',
    }
    return render(request, 'main/league_detail_more.html', context=context)
```

In `league` template, i pass `{% url 'league_detail' match.pk %}` to get queryset from `Match` into `league_detail` template and in `league_detail` template i pass `{% url 'league_detail_more' match.pk %}`**---here is the main problem..it pass all the pk of `Match` but i need to pass match.pk and match.mega_league.pk** to get queryset from `Match` into `league_detail_more` template..

In all template i use `for` loop..it's working...but to get specific pk query is not working..

It is working for `league_detail` template but not for `league_detail_more` template..in `league_detail_more` template pk pass from `league_detail` is not working.

How can i get the all the queryset clearly for both template using `match = get_object_or_404(Match, pk=pk)`??

Comment: Sorry, once again your question is not clear. What "specific pk query" is not working? What *exactly* do you see and how is that different from what you want?

Comment: sir, look at the models, in `Match` there are manytomany field `MegaLeague` and in `MegaLeague` there are also manytomany field `MegaPricePoolBreak`...
so , in league_detail template i use  `{% for mega_league in match.mega_league.all %}` to get `mega_league` query and in `league_detail_more`  template i also use `{% for mega_league in match.mega_league.all %}` to get mega_league query...but in this tamplate i need only one queryset...don't want to use `for` loop but also want to access the `Match` query data...

Comment: in views i can use this `mega = get_object_or_404(MegaLeague, pk=pk)`
and then i can get the `Match` queryset using `mega.match_set` ...but then i can find the all queryset of `Match` ..because it is the manytomany field of `MegaLeague`... i need the one queryset using pk

Comment: In one word, i need to pass two pk for `Match` queryset and `MegaLeague` queryset in this `{% url 'league_detail_more' match.pk %}` url at a time....how can it possible @DanielRoseman sir

Answer (score 0):

I still don't really understand where you're having problems.

If you just want to pass two IDs to a URL, that is simple:

```
path('league_detail_more/<int:match_id>/<int:league_id>/', league_detail_more, name='league_detail_more')
```

and in the view:

```
def league_detail_more(request, match_id, league_id):
    match = get_object_or_404(Match, pk=match_id)
    league = get_object_or_404(MegaLeague, pk=league_id)
```

Comment: then what will be the `{% url 'league_detail_more' match.pk %}` to pass both IDs

Comment: Well you do it by passing both IDs of course: `{% url 'league_detail_more' match.pk league.pk %}` or whatever the league variable is.